# C# Impersonate to Save on NAS drive not working

Tags: c#, impersonation, advapi32

I've been trying to implement the impersonation on my c# application to save files on NAS drive, but even though my credentials are valid. I keep getting an error as **The username or password is incorrect**. it worked a couple of times and then it kept failing. this happened when I deployed it on IIS.

```
 if (RevertToSelf())
            {
                if (LogonUser(AppConstants.NASAccessUserName, AppConstants.NASServerDomain,
                    AppConstants.NASAccessPassword, LogonType.Interactive,
                    LogonProvider.Default, out _token))
                {
                    if (DuplicateToken(_token, SecurityImpersonationLevel.Impersonation, out _tokenDuplicate))
                    {

                        var tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(_tokenDuplicate);
                        _impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                        return true;
                    }
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
```

I've tried using LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS as the logon Type too along with LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50, but no luck. what am I missing here? is there any configuration on the NAS server? or anything else to add to this?

Answer (score 0):

Have this in your config file?

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

Comment: Yes, I have added that too :(

Comment: anything else you could think of?

Comment: btw, i changed the logon type to network. now the error has changed. it shows as **access to path is denied** but i have given the access to the specific user on the drive folder

Comment: @Isham What negotiation protocol? Kerberos or NTLM?

Comment: the protocol is NTLM

Comment: @Isham See if anything here helps https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/810572/how-to-configure-an-asp-net-application-for-a-delegation-scenario

Comment: thanks for your support, I resolved it by using the option as newcredential as the LogonType.